# What does `typedef` mean in this context

Tags: c, typedef

I am sure this question has been asked before. But I am wondering what does the `typedef` mean in this code:

```
typedef long (*HASH_CONS_HASH)(void *);
typedef bool (*HASH_CONS_EQUAL(void *, void *));
```

So far I understand:

- `HASH_CONS_HASH` is a function that takes a `void*` and returns `long`
- `HASH_CONS_EQUAL` is a function that takes two arguments of type `void*` and returns `bool`

But what does `typedef` mean here? is it necessary?

Comment: You're right, it took me 10 seconds to find a LOT of questions about typedef.  VTC as duplicate, duplicate, duplicate.

Comment: The typedef allows one to use, eg, variables of the type to which any conforming function pointer can be assigned.

Comment: No, this question is _not_ about “typedef struct”, as a cursory reading would reveal. Voted to re-open the poor closing. (There might be other duplicates; this is not it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares the function pointer ***type***.

now you can define `HASH_CONS_HASH func1;` where func1 is a pointer to the function returning long and not taking any parameters

or
`HASH_CONS_EQUAL func2;` where `func2` is a pointer to function returning `bool` and taking two void pointer as parameters.